# Return multiple React elements in a method without a wrapper element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to return multiple React elements from a helper method. I could solve it simply by moving around some code, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to solve it. I have a method that returns part of the `render` method, and that functions needs to return both a React element and some text. It's clearer through an example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  _renderAuthor() {
    if (!this.props.author) {
      return null;
    }

    return [
      ' by ',
      <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
    ]; // Triggers warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.title}
        {this._renderAuthor()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know the `render` method has to return exactly 1 React element. Using a helper method like this would trigger a warning, and fixing the warning (by adding keys) would make the code too convoluted. Is there a clean way to do this without triggering a warning?

**Edit:**

Another use case:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {user
        ? <h2>{user.name}</h2>
          <p>{user.info}</p>
        : <p>User not found</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Turns out this isn't possible yet, I wrote about 2 workarounds here: https://www.wptutor.io/web/js/react-multiple-elements-without-wrapper

Comment: what kinda warning?

Comment: "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." It's impossible to add a key to the text node. Even if I could, it seems very awkward to add keys when I'm just trying to return 2 fixed elements.

Comment: When you dynamically insert additional elements in React it looks for key prop so when you render your link do this: `<a key = {'prefix-'+random_string_generator()} href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>`

Comment: Yes but I'm looking for a method where I don't have to do that.

Comment: I understand this is not the most pleasing way to fix this. I personally would like a better resolution to this as well however I haven't seen an alternative suggestion that works either.

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar Thanks for confirming that you also don't have a better method, I assumed that was the case, but I asked just to be sure.

Comment: @LeoJiang in these two case it can be voided to have multiple children.
In the first example you can return <span>by <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a></span>. Instead of the array.
In the second one you can move the condition around the div.

Comment: FWIW, they're working on adding official support for this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127

Comment: @TomDavies I think that's the closest to a correct answer. If you make that comment an answer, I'll accept that as the correct answer if no other answers come up before the bounty expires.

Comment: @LeoJiang answered. I'm sure I saw a talk from FB where they talked about this and mentioned how awkward randomly adding `<div>`s and things to wrap was - if I find it I'll add it in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this without some sort of workaround like wrapping everything in another component, since it ends up with the underlying React code trying to return multiple objects.

See [this active Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127) where support for this is being considered for a future version though.

---

Edit: You *can* now do this with Fragments in React 16, see:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Comment: While this doesn't fix the issue directly, it confirms that what I'm trying to do isn't possible. The thread gave me some ideas for 2 workarounds. I wrote about the workarounds here: https://www.wptutor.io/web/js/react-multiple-elements-without-wrapper

Answer (score 14):

Support has been added using the Fragment component. This is a first-class component.

So you can now use:

```jsx
render() {
  return (   
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

For more information visit: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Comment: `<></>` is the same, however `React.Fragment` can accept attributes like `key`, which is useful.

Answer (score 12):

The error message tells you exactly how to solve this:

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Instead of this:

```
return [
  ' by ',
  <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
];
```

Do this:

```
return [
  <span key="by"> by </span>,
  <a key="author" href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
];
```

Yes, you need to wrap the text node ("by") in a span in order to give it a key. Such are the breaks. As you can see, I've just given each element a static `key`, since there's nothing dynamic about them. You could just as well use `key="1"` and `key="2"` if you wanted.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
return <span> by <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a></span>;
```

...which obviates the need for `key`s.

Here's the former solution in a working snippet:

```js
const getAuthorUrl = author => `/${author.toLowerCase()}`;

class Foo extends React.Component {
  _renderAuthor() {
    if (!this.props.author) {
      return null;
    }

    return [
      <span key="by"> by </span>,
      <a key="author" href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.datePosted}
        {this._renderAuthor()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo datePosted="Today" author="Me"/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is it adds unnecessary markup and JSX. Perhaps my question wasn't clear, but I'm looking for a method where I won't have to use `key`. I'm assuming it isn't possible, but I asked on SO just in case.

Comment: you have to use keys when rendering an array of elements its part of React's way of identifying elements https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: If I _have to_ use keys with arrays, then I'm looking for a method that doesn't use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to solve this. I will suggest you create another component Author.js:

```
function Author(props) {
  return (<span>
    <span> by </span>
    <a href={props.getAuthorUrl(props.author)}>{props.author}</a>
  </span>)
}


class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.title}
        {this.props.author && <Author author={this.props.author} getAuthorUrl={this.getAuthorUrl} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I didn't test this code though. But it will look more cleaner I think. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have an If-component around for such things, and I have wrapped everything into a span, as it doesn't really break anything and makes the need for keys go away...

```js
const getAuthorUrl = author => `/${author.toLowerCase()}`;

function If({condition,children}) {
  return condition ? React.Children.only(children) : null;

}

class Foo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.datePosted}
        <If condition={this.props.author}>
          <span> by 
          <a key="author" href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>
            {this.props.author}
          </a>
          </span>
        </If>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo datePosted="Today" author="Me"/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

...skipping the array thing altogether?

Comment: You're still wrapping a `<span>` around the text and the `<a>`. I could also wrap a `<span>` instead of using the array, but I don't want extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but it doesn't have unnecessary jsx as you wished.

```
var author = 'Daniel';
var title = 'Hello';

var Hello = React.createClass({
  _renderAutho0r: function() {
    if (!author) {
      return null;
    }

    return <a href="#">{author}</a>
},

    render: function() {
    var by = author ? ' by ' : null;

        return (
      <div>
        {title}
        {by}
        {this._renderAutho0r()}
      </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovothebest/o4nqpkLb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can return fragments from sub-rendering functions but not from the main render function, at least before React 16. In order to do so, return an array of components. You don't need to set keys manually unless your fragment children will change (arrays are keyed with indices by default).

For creating fragments you may also use [`createFragment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-create-fragment).

For inline usage, you may use an array or leverage immediately invoked arrow function.
See the example below:

```js
const getAuthorUrl = author => `/${author.toLowerCase()}`;

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this._renderAuthor = this._renderAuthor.bind(this);
     this._renderUser = this._renderUser.bind(this);
  }
  
  _renderAuthor() {
    if (!this.props.author) {
      return null;
    }

    return [
      ' by ',
      <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
    ];
  }
  
  _renderUser() {
    return [
      <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
      <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
    ]
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.datePosted}
        {this._renderAuthor()}
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? this._renderUser()
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? [
                <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
                <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
              ]
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? (() => [
                <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
                <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
              ])()
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo datePosted="Today" author="Me" user={{name: 'test', info: 'info'}} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

In order to not get warnings each child must be assigned a key. In order to do so, instead of returning an array please use helper function `fragment(...children)` to assign index-based keys automatically. Please note that strings must be converted to spans or other nodes that can be assigned with a key:

```
const fragment = (...children) =>
    children.map((child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(
            typeof child === 'string'
            ? <span>{child}</span>
            : child
        , { key: index }
        )
    )
```

```js
const getAuthorUrl = author => `/${author.toLowerCase()}`;

const fragment = (...children) =>
    children.map((child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(
            typeof child === 'string'
            ? <span>{child}</span>
            : child
        , { key: index }
        )
    )

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this._renderAuthor = this._renderAuthor.bind(this);
     this._renderUser = this._renderUser.bind(this);
  }
  
  _renderAuthor() {
    if (!this.props.author) {
      return null;
    }

    return fragment(
      ' by ',
      <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>
    );
  }
  
  _renderUser() {
    return fragment(
      <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
      <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
    )
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.datePosted}
        {this._renderAuthor()}
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? this._renderUser()
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? fragment(
                <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
                <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
              )
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
        
        <div>
          {this.props.user
            ? (() => fragment(
                <h2>{this.props.user.name}</h2>,
                <p>{this.props.user.info}</p>
              ))()
            : <p>User not found</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo datePosted="Today" author="Me" user={{name: 'test', info: 'info'}} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the React file you're using has its warnings stripped. I guess it's a viable option to just remove the warning.

Comment: I wasn't aware of warnings as they are not shown herein the snippets. To get rid of those please see the edited answer with `fragment` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    _renderAuthor() {
        return <a href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
                {this.props.title}
                {this.props.author && " by "}
                {this.props.author && this._renderAuthor()}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more simple way would be to rethink how you're architecting your application. However, in a more simple way.

You're triggering the warning because you're trying to render from an array and not react elements but directly html. In order to approach this, you would have to do

```
{this._renderAuthor().map(
    (k,i) => (React.addons.createFragment({k}))
    )  }
```

`React addons` `createFragment` function basically does that, it reduces your html elements into react fragments that you can render.

[React createFragment documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html)

Alternatively, in a much better approach, you can create an AuthorLink `stateless` component like this..

```
function AuthorLink(props) {
  return (
    <div className="author-link">
      <span> by </span>
      <a href={props.authorUrl}> {props.author} </a>
    </div> 
  });
}
```

and use this in your main component's render

```
render() {
  const { author } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.datePosted}
      <AuthorLink url={getAuthorUrl(author)} author={author} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this approach on your array:

```
return [
      <span key={'prefix-'+random_string_generator()}>' by '</span>,
      <a key={'prefix-'+random_string_generator()} href={getAuthorUrl(this.props.author)}>{this.props.author}</a>,
    ];
```

Comment: 1. You basically copied this from @JustinMUcar's comment above, so -1, and 2. `random_string_generator()` pretty much defeats the purpose of `key`, which is to aid in virtual DOM [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html). It makes the warning go away, but it's pretty much the worst possible solution.