# Return multiple elements from React Component

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a component that renders a table with appropriate styling. It is, at the moment, a single monolithic component that takes a huge chunk of data defining columns and data for all the rows.

```
<MyTable
    columns={myColumnList}
    data={myTableData}
/>
```

One of the key features of this table is that it will render two rows if there is additional data not defined in the list of columns. So selecting a row will reveal additional data not displayed in the table.

I would like to break this component into smaller elements so that I can use only the bits that I need or use alternatives. Something like:

```
<MyTable>
<MyTableHeader columns={myColumnList} />
<MyTableBody>
    <MyTableRow data={row1Data} />
    <MyTableRow data={row2Data} />
    <MyTableRow data={row3Data} />
</MyTableBody>
<MyTableFooter />
</MyTable>
```

But,  could produce two rows. To do this I would need a component that could potentially have to render two  elements.

The normal way to return multiple elements from a component is to wrap it in a  but that is invalid html within a table.

Is there any way that I can have a React Component that renders multiple elements without wrapping them a single ?

Or, is there a simpler solution that I have missed.

Comment: I believe that you question should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any reason? I am not asking whether my code is good merely explaining why I need a component that returns multiple elements and why it cannot be wrapped in a <div>

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122121/return-multiple-react-elements-in-a-method-without-a-wrapper-element

Comment: @ThomasArbona That question relates to a helper function. In fact that is what my monolithic component is doing at the moment - returning an array of two rows. What I am trying to do is take this out as a separate component.

Answer (score 0):

A `<table>` can have multiple `<tbody>` children, so one option would be for the "row" component to return something like:

```
<tbody>
    <trow></trow>
    <trow></trow>
</tbody>
```

If you did this, you should remove the "body" component that was wrapping your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which returns the elements you need.

```
  const fun = (items) => items.map((item) => <tr key={item.id}>item.name</tr>);
```

Call it inside the table body:

```
<tbody>
{fun(items)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Don't forget that array items should have keys, and I guess you mean `tbody`, not `body`.